# A question about unitary matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have already this question, but since I answered my own question in inappropriate place (blow my question), this leads to "put on hold as off-topic" situation. So I again ask my question.

**My question:**

Let
$$A=\left[\begin{array}{cc} \mu & x \\ y & U \end{array}\right],$$
where $\mu\in\mathbb{C}$, $x\in\mathbb{C}^{1\times n}$, $y\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times 1}$ and $U\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$. If $A$ is unitary, then show that $|\det(U)|=|\mu|$.

**My answer:**

In fact, as $A$ is unitary, then $A^*A=I$, so we have
\begin{equation}
 \left[\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0_{1\times n} \\ 0_{n\times 1} & I_{n\times n} \end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{cc} \bar{\mu} & y^* \\ x^* & U^* \end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{cc} \mu & x \\ y & U \end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{cc} |\mu|^2+\Arrowvert y\Arrowvert_2^2 & \bar{\mu}x+y^*U \\ \mu x^*+U^*y & x^*x+U^*U \end{array}\right],
\end{equation}
where $I$ is an identity matrix.

In my opinion, two cases must be considered.

**Case 1:**  $\mu=0$. If $\mu=0$, based on relation above, it yields $\Arrowvert y\Arrowvert_2=1$ and so $y\neq 0$ and then there exits a nonzero vactor y such that $U^*y=0$. Hence $U$ is singular and $\det(U)=0$, so $|\det(U)|=|\mu|=0$.

**Case 2:** $\mu\neq 0$. In this case, I can't prove anything.

Comment: Have you try to multiply from the other side, i.e. $AA^*=I$, and see what happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: combine two facts

1. You have got $x^*x+U^*U=I$ that gives $U^*U=I-x^*x$, then $$\underbrace{\det(U^*U)}_{=|\det(U)|^2}=\det(I-x^*x)=\det(1-xx^*)=1-\|x\|^2.$$
2. When you multiply from the other side $AA^*=I$, you'll get $|\mu|^2+\|x\|^2=1$.

P.S. In the first fact [Sylvester's determinant identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester's_determinant_identity) were used.